Ставятся ли здесь запятые?
Хотя (?) по описанию девушки (?) он всё тот же.
Нужно ли обособить запятыми выражение "по описанию девушки"? Подразумевается "судя по описанию девушки". Объясните, пожалуйста.

если прямо из описания девушки, то я бы так написал. Хотя по описанию девушки - "он всё тот же". То есть - девушка описала его: "он всё тот же"

"Выражение «по описанию девушки»". А это выражение?

словосочетание, если хотите. зачем придираться к словам?

Правильно: Хотя, по описанию девушки, он всё тот же.

Это вводное сочетание со значением источника информации. Этот  вариант аналогичен сочетанию: По словам (кого, чьим), в составе вводного сочетания.

Справочник
Вводные сочетания «по словам (кого-либо, чьим-либо)», указывающие на источник сообщения, обособляются. ! Не смешивать с употреблением в роли члена предложения.

Сравнить: По описанию девушки был составлен фоторобот. Член предложения не обособляется.

